# How to use .htaccess file on windows server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I using GoDaddy products. I've one hosting and last week I changed linux to windows server.
After I changed hosting type, unfortunatelly the 404 redirection doesn't working..

I've .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http//www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$                                       viewcontent.php?id=$1                            [NS]
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$                                        haberler.php?id=$1                               [NS]
RewriteRule sitemap.xml                                       xml.php                                          [NS]
```

How I can use this links on windows hosting.. what I have to do?

Btw, I think GoDaddy windows hosting doesn't support apache. So I can't use .htaccess

Thanks for helps.

Comment: The Windows Server will undoubtedly use IIS. Was there a reason why you swapped from a Linux server to Windows?

Comment: Godaddy windows uses iis server, so you need web.config file. Try this: http://www.htaccesstowebconfig.com/ or change back to linux!!

Answer (score 2):

in IIS you use web.config not .htaccess

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig